# MYSQL using TIME Between in TimeRange

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I am facing a weird problem related with MySQL time that I am not able to solve at all.

```
Table:landing
landingPage (varchar) - mylanding.html
starttime (time): 18:00:00
endTime (time) : 04:00:00
```

The requirement is to display the landingPage between 18:00:00 and 04:00:00 which is 6 pm to 4 am. I am using following query

```
select landingPage from landing where currentTime between starttime and endtime.
```

The above query works from 18:00:00  to  23:59:59.  But after midnight it doesn't show any values.  For an instance

```
select landingPage from landing where '02:00:00' between starttime and endtime.
```

I have even tried the following query but after midnight the same issue.

```
select landingPage from landing where currentTime>starttime AND currentTime<endtime
```

It's a Java application and should I use AM/PM logic here ?

Comment: Maybe MySQL is doing strange things with the type of `currentTime`. As what Java type are you passing it? What happens if you use [`curtime()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems comes from the fact that after midnight, the hour goes back to `00:00:00` so the interval `[18:00:00, 04:00:00]` is empty: when the days are not considered, no hour can be greater than `18h` while being lower than `4h` on the same day.

You could implement the following logic: show the landing page

- if the hour is lower than `04:00:00`: it would mean that the hour is between midnight and `04:00:00`;
- or if the hour is greather than `18:00:00`: it would mean that the hour is between `18:00:00` and midnight.

The query becomes:

```
select landingPage from landing where currentTime < endTime OR currentTime > startTime
```

Comment: Thanks for editing and answering my question. I tested this query and it displayed the correct result for me.